# Aligning equations inside separate \begin[split] functions

Tags: amsmath, amssymb

I am trying to include a couple split environments inside an align environment, and I was wondering if there was any way to align the equations inside the split environment with the equations outside of them?

```
\begin{align}
    y_{1}^{'} &= -\mu x^{\lambda - 1}sin(\mu \ln(x))+ x^{\lambda - 1} cos(\mu \ln(x))\\
    y_{2}^{'} &= \mu x^{\lambda - 1}cos(\mu \ln(x))+ x^{\lambda - 1} sin(\mu \ln(x)) \\ 
\begin{split}
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= (\mu x^{2\lambda - 1} cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + x^{2\lambda -1} sin(\mu 
\ln(x))cos(\mu \ln(x))) \\
    & - (-\mu x^{2\lambda - 1}sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x))+x^{2\lambda - 1}cos(\mu \ln(x))sin(\mu \ln(x))) \\
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= x^{2\lambda - 1}[(\mu  cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + sin(\mu \ln(x))cos(\mu \ln(x))) \\
    & - (-\mu sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x))+cos(\mu \ln(x))sin(\mu \ln(x)))] \\
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= x^{2\lambda - 1}[\mu  cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + sin(\mu \ln(x))cos(\mu \ln(x)) \\
    & + \mu sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) - cos(\mu \ln(x))sin(\mu \ln(x)))] \\
\end{split}\\
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= x^{2\lambda - 1} [\mu sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + \mu cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x))]\\
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= x^{2\lambda - 1} [\mu (sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)))]\\
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= \mu x^{2\lambda - 1}
\end{align}
```

Comment: it's a lot easier if you post full documnts, also possibly unrelated you want `\sin` not `sin`

Comment: Off-topic: `^{'}` is wrong. Instead, write either `^{\prime}` or -- much more simply -- `'`.

Answer (score 6):

There's no need to embed `split` environments inside the `align` environment. A single `align` environment, along with judiciously placed `\notag` and `\quad` instructions, is all that's required to get the formatting job done.

[image]

Observe that I've also replaced (a) both instances of `^{'}` with `'` and (b) all instances of `sin` and `cos` with `\sin` and `\cos`, respectively. Also, there's no need to repeat `W(y_{1},y_{2})` on the left hand sides of equations (4) thru (8)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    y_{1}' &= -\mu x^{\lambda-1}\sin(\mu \ln(x))+ x^{\lambda-1} \cos(\mu \ln(x))\\
    y_{2}' &=  \mu x^{\lambda-1}\cos(\mu \ln(x))+ x^{\lambda-1} \sin(\mu \ln(x)) \\ 
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) 
    &= (\mu x^{2\lambda-1} \cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + x^{2\lambda-1} \sin(\mu \ln(x))\cos(\mu \ln(x))) \notag\\
    &\quad- (-\mu x^{2\lambda-1}\sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x))+x^{2\lambda-1}\cos(\mu \ln(x))\sin(\mu \ln(x))) \\
    %W(y_{1},y_{2}) 
    &= x^{2\lambda-1}[(\mu  \cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + \sin(\mu \ln(x))\cos(\mu \ln(x))) \notag \\
    &\quad-(-\mu \sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x))+cos(\mu \ln(x))\sin(\mu \ln(x)))]\\
    %W(y_{1},y_{2}) 
    &= x^{2\lambda-1}[\mu  \cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + \sin(\mu \ln(x))\cos(\mu \ln(x)) \notag\\
    &\quad + \mu \sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x))-\cos(\mu \ln(x))\sin(\mu \ln(x)))] \\
    %W(y_{1},y_{2}) 
    &= x^{2\lambda-1} [\mu \sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + \mu \cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x))]\\
    %W(y_{1},y_{2}) 
    &= x^{2\lambda-1} [\mu (\sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + \cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)))]\\
    %W(y_{1},y_{2}) 
    &= \mu x^{2\lambda-1} \,.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`split` always aligns with the outer alignment, but the spurious trailing `\\`  confused it

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    y_{1}' &= -\mu x^{\lambda - 1}\sin(\mu \ln(x))+ x^{\lambda - 1} \cos(\mu \ln(x))\\
    y_{2}' &= \mu x^{\lambda - 1}\cos(\mu \ln(x))+ x^{\lambda - 1} \sin(\mu \ln(x)) \\ 
\begin{split}
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= (\mu x^{2\lambda - 1} \cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + x^{2\lambda -1} \sin(\mu 
\ln(x))\cos(\mu \ln(x))) \\
    & - (-\mu x^{2\lambda - 1}\sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x))+x^{2\lambda - 1}\cos(\mu \ln(x))\sin(\mu \ln(x)))
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= x^{2\lambda - 1}[(\mu  \cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + \sin(\mu \ln(x))\cos(\mu \ln(x))) \\
    & - (-\mu \sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x))+\cos(\mu \ln(x))\sin(\mu \ln(x)))]
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= x^{2\lambda - 1}[\mu  \cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + \sin(\mu \ln(x))\cos(\mu \ln(x)) \\
    & + \mu \sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) - \cos(\mu \ln(x))\sin(\mu \ln(x)))]
\end{split}\\
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= x^{2\lambda - 1} [\mu \sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + \mu \cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x))]\\
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= x^{2\lambda - 1} [\mu (\sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + \cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)))]\\
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= \mu x^{2\lambda - 1}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico ah I missed one, update coming up....

Comment: @Mico `\\ ` deleted

Answer (score 3):

Never have a trailing `\\` in `amsmath` alignment environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    y_{1}' &= -\mu x^{\lambda - 1}\sin(\mu \ln(x))+ x^{\lambda - 1} \cos(\mu \ln(x))\\
    y_{2}' &= \mu x^{\lambda - 1}\cos(\mu \ln(x))+ x^{\lambda - 1} \sin(\mu \ln(x)) \\
\begin{split}
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= (\mu x^{2\lambda - 1} \cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + x^{2\lambda -1} \sin(\mu 
\ln(x))\cos(\mu \ln(x))) \\
    & - (-\mu x^{2\lambda - 1}\sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x))+x^{2\lambda - 1}\cos(\mu \ln(x))\sin(\mu \ln(x)))
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= x^{2\lambda - 1}[(\mu  \cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + \sin(\mu \ln(x))\cos(\mu \ln(x))) \\
    & - (-\mu \sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x))+\cos(\mu \ln(x))\sin(\mu \ln(x)))]
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= x^{2\lambda - 1}[\mu  \cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + \sin(\mu \ln(x))\cos(\mu \ln(x)) \\
    & + \mu \sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) - \cos(\mu \ln(x))\sin(\mu \ln(x)))]
\end{split}\\
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= x^{2\lambda - 1} [\mu \sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + \mu \cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x))]\\
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= x^{2\lambda - 1} [\mu (\sin^{2}(\mu \ln(x)) + \cos^{2}(\mu \ln(x)))]\\
    W(y_{1},y_{2}) &= \mu x^{2\lambda - 1}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I fixed all `sin` and `cos` to be `\sin` and `\cos`; also `^{'}` should be just `'`.

[image]